# No space between ms word numbering and some but not all headers

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I'm using numbering list, however, on some of the headers I get no space between the numbering and the headers.

I've included an image in which you can see how there is no space between 2.8 Laravel and 2.9 Eloquent ORM, however, there's more than enough space between 2.10 Composer and 2.11 Apache.

Any idea why is this happening?

[image]

Comment: Check your tab stops in the heading style.

Comment: Can you explain what am I supposed to do? Frankly I wouldn't know what to even look for after going in the tab menu. It's weird because it's the first time something like that has ever happened and in only happens to some of the headers which are the same type "Heading 2"

Comment: Post up a small example document.